# how to use X-Forwarded-Prefix in file backend

Tags: http-headers, reverse-proxy, grafana, traefik

I'm try to configure traefik with file backend to contact a grafana server in a LXC container.

This is my configuration file:

```
[file]
# rules
[backends]
  [backends.backend2.servers.server1]
     url = "http://192.168.255.250:3000"
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend2]
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    backend = "backend2"
    passHostHeader = true
      [frontends.frontend2.routes]
      [frontends.frontend2.routes.route0]
        rule = "PathPrefixStrip: /grafana"
```

Grafana backend listen on /

So, I can contact http://example.com/grafana but I have a redirection to http://example.com/login which does not work. But  http://example.com/grafana/login responding (without css, certainly because grafana seems to use relative url).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#frontends) :

> Use a *Strip matcher if your backend listens on the root path (/) but should be routeable on a specific prefix. For instance, PathPrefixStrip: /products would match /products but also /products/shoes and /products/shirts.
>   Since the path is stripped prior to forwarding, your backend is expected to listen on /.
>   If your backend is serving assets (e.g., images or Javascript files), chances are it must return properly constructed relative URLs.
>   Continuing on the example, the backend should return /products/shoes/image.png (and not /images.png which Traefik would likely not be able to associate with the same backend).
>   The X-Forwarded-Prefix header (available since Traefik 1.3) can be queried to build such URLs dynamically.

It seems that I have to use the X-Forwarded-Prefix header but I do not know how to use it (I did not see anything in the documentation). Maybe you can help me solve this problem ?

Regards

jmc

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem does not come from traefik. I just forgot to specify the path in /etc/grafana.ini (root_url field). I thought it was not necessary since the incoming query does not contain the path /grafana (because we use PathPrefixStrip). But in fact, grafana needs it to indicate effective url to client.

Regards.

jmc